# What aircraft was used as Air Force One for the flight between Southampton and Shannon?

Tags: aircraft-identification

On Wednesday 5th June 2019, The US President flew from Southampton Airport, UK to Shannon Airport, Ireland on Air Force One.

However, since SOU is more of a small regional airport, more used to seeing Dash-8s, the runway isn't very long so the aircraft used wasn't the usual B747-200, it was this much smaller aircraft.

[image: Smaller Air Force One]

Can anyone identify the type? My guess would be a B737-600?

Comment: The "drooped" appearance of the nosecone is one quick clue that it is not a 737--

Comment: Cute nose, big eyes, big wing, tall legs, slim body, not a 737 indeed ;)

Comment: Boeing windscreen (and it'd be funny if the POTUS used an Airbus), four-wheeled main undercarriage and four grown-up doors => 757 or 767, nosewheel underneath front door => clearly a 757

Comment: The sheer amount of "stuff" has travels around the world with the POTUS is frankly shocking. How many planes does one person need!?

Comment: that's a nice photo

Comment: :-O I didn't realise that Air Force One was more than one plane! Is AF1 basically whatever plane the president happens to be using?

Comment: @AaronF Air Force One is any Air Force plane on which the President happens to be at the time. If the President is not on board, it is not Air Force One, but rather goes by something like "SAM <tail number>" (SAM stands for "Special Air Mission.") The primary planes used as Air Force One are the VC-25s (the modified Air Force Boeing 747s,) of which there are two. But the C-32As get used as Air Force One somewhat frequently as well, particularly when the President needs to fly somewhere without a runway long enough for the VC-25s.

Comment: @AaronF If the President is on an aircraft that isn't owned by the Air Force, then it's called "<military branch> One" if it's a different military branch (e.g. "Marine One," "Navy One," etc.) or "Executive One" if it's a civilian aircraft. This is why the Presidential transport helicopter (which is owned by the U.S. Marine Corps) is called Marine One when the President is on board.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As Bianfable mentioned, this is the [C-32A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_C-32), which is the U.S. Air Force's transport variant of the [Boeing 757-200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_757#Government,_military,_and_corporate).

In this case, due to the shorter runway, they used the C-32A instead of the iconic [VC-25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_VC-25), which is the Air Force's VIP transport variant of the Boeing 747-200 that is typically used for transporting the President of the United States.

[image: U.S. Air Force C-32A. Source: Wikipedia]
U.S. Air Force C-32A. Image Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_757#/media/File:Air_Force_Two_lands_at_the_Kentucky_Air_National_Guard_Base,_Louisville,_Ky.jpg)

The C-32As are mostly used for transporting the Vice President of the United States as "Air Force Two" as well as members of the President's family and other high-level government officials.

However, the President may use the C-32As when flying to airfields that are too small to adequately support the monstrous VC-25s. The short-field performance of a 757 — especially a VIP-configured one — is quite good, so it can use runways that are relatively short for a plane of its size. It is also capable of making trans-Atlantic hops non-stop from the U.S. East Coast (indeed several airlines use the 757-200 to do that with much more dense passenger loads.)

Comment: Just noticed from the article that the [1st Airlift Squadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_Airlift_Squadron) is the operator, which seems different from the VC-25 (don't know which), so different squadrons it seems as well.

Comment: @ymb1 Hmm... I can't seem to find an exact squadron for the VC-25s from a quick search, but it looks like [they're part of the 89th Airlift Wing](https://www.af.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/104588/vc-25-air-force-one/), of which the 1st Squadron is also a part. The 1st Squadron's wiki does say that they are assigned to the Special Air Mission, including transporting the President, but you're right that it makes no mention of the VC-25s, which would be a very odd thing to leave out if they operated them.

Comment: @ymb1 Ah, the [wiki for the SAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Air_Mission#Assignments) lists a separate "Presidential Airlift Squadron," so I'd guess that probably operates the VC-25s.

Comment: Perfect, I couldn't find it too with a quick search. Thanks.

Comment: Also fun fact, The Trump Organization owns a private 757 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_Force_One)

Comment: @SnakeDoc Yeah, that was Trump's plane before he became President, including during his campaign. Definitely a sweet ride for a private jet, though a VC-25 it is not.

Answer (score 22):

It is a [Boeing C-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_C-32), which is the military variant of the Boeing 757-200.